# Nonlinear Optimization Problem with nonlinear constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

How can i solve this problem?

$$\max_{a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R} \sqrt{a^2+(3-b)^2}+\sqrt{(b-c)^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+(1-d)^2}$$
\begin{align*}
\text{subject to: }&\qquad  0 \le a \le 1, \quad 1 \le b \le 2,\quad 1 \le c \le b,\quad 0 \le d \le 1
\\ &\sqrt{a^2+(3-b)^2} \le \sqrt{(1-a)^2+(3-c)^2}\quad \text{and}\quad  \sqrt{c^2+(1-d)^2} \le \sqrt{d^2+b^2}\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Solve the unconstrained problem which leads to

$$ a=0, \;\;\; b=3, \;\;\; c=0, \;\;\; d=1, \;\;\; $$

and notice that the only constraint that is violated is $b \le 2$.

Then, solve the problem with only this constraint which leads to

$$ a=0, \;\;\; b=2, \;\;\; c=0, \;\;\; d=1, \;\;\; $$

and notice that none of the constraints is violated.